# Dataflow uploading file encoding error

Tags: encoding, gcloud, dataflow

My development environment uses Eclipse OXYGEN, Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse 1.7.0 installed.

I create Google cloud Dataflow Java Project.

There was a problem testing wordcount example.

When reading a file in the bucket, it will be output normally from the log as follows.

[image]

The problem occurs when you process data for WordCount and store the data in the bucket.

[image]

If you check the saved file, you can see the above picture.

Does dataflow not support Korean language?

here is my TextIO.write Codes

```
static class WriteData extends PTransform<PCollection<KV<URI, String>>, PDone>
{
    private String output;

    public WriteData(String output)
    {
          this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    public Coder<?> getDefaultOutputCoder()
    {
        return KvCoder.of(StringDelegateCoder.of(URI.class), StringUtf8Coder.of());
    }

    @Override
    public PDone expand(PCollection<KV<URI, String>> outputfile) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return outputfile
                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<URI, String>, String>(){
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
                    {
                        output = c.element().getKey().toString();
                        LOG.info("WRITE DATA : " + c.element().getValue());
                        c.output(c.element().getValue());
                    }
                }))
                .apply(TextIO.write().to(output).withSuffix(".txt"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the correct coder can be automatically inferred, but if it doesn't, then make sure you're specifying a coder when reading data.

When you need to specify the coder, you typically need to do it when reading data into your pipeline from an external source (or creating pipeline data from local data), and also when you output pipeline data to an external sink.

For example, you can decode the data to read:

```
StringUtf8Coder.of().decode(inStream)
```